# Where is the error log file destination for Zookeeper distributed with Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm a bit confused on how to configure where the error log files are written for Zookeeper when running ZK and Kafka on the same node.  I understand it uses log4j and there is a zookeeper.properties file.  I assume it is using some sort of default out of the box.  If I do:

```
sudo lsof -p 31311 | grep log | grep zoo
```

I get:

```
java    31311 root    1w      REG              259,1     24962  134739 /home/ec2-user/zookeeper-start-log
java    31311 root    2w      REG              259,1     24962  134739 /home/ec2-user/zookeeper-start-log
java    31311 root    3w      REG              259,1     22350 1050171 /opt/Kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/logs/zookeeper-gc.log.0.current
java    31311 root   94w      REG              259,1  67108880  394260 /var/local/zookeeper/data/version-2/log.1
```

If I want to explicitly specify my error log locations for zookeeper, what exactly do I specify in the zookeeper.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the provided `zookeeper-server-start` script, then Kafka and Zookeeper share the same `log4j.properties` file.

In there, you can reconfigure the DailyRollingFileAppender or ConsoleAppender based on the package names for Zookeeper clients and/or Kafka

If you want to reconfigure the data stored by Zookeeper other than the service logs, the Zookeeper documentation should cover those as well as the defaults

Comment: btw, it's not recommended to run your services as root

Comment: How do I specify a separate file being used for logging zookeeper messages from Kafka messages then?

Comment: They should already be separate. The broker server log, log cleaner, controller, etc are all separate files in the log4j file, but it's not recommended to run the brokers on the same servers as Zookeeper in a production setup, so you wouldn't have to worry about that anyway

Comment: So the answer to the original question is "there is no error log file by default for zookeeper".  Right?   I'm not seeing any files in the logs directory for zookeeper and the log4j.properties file doesn't appear to have anything setting a specific file for zookeeper.

Comment: @Ryan As answered, there is only one `log4.properties` for both Zookeeper and Kafka. Whether you actually get files or not depends how the file is configured. This applies to almost all Java services, in fact. [By default, Zookeeper just goes to stdout, while Kafka goes to various files.](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties#L18)

Comment: In other words, create some `zooAppender` [on this line](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties#L61) and configure it with a DailyRollingFileAppender like `kafkaAppender`. Then you get files.

Comment: Alternatively - [use `apt-get`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html), for example, then you [would get your logs from `journalctl`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs)

Comment: Yeah, I added a zooAppender and got a dedicated file for zookeeper to aid in debugging.   However, looks like some of the same logging is also showing up in server.log.  I guess zookeeper logging was in server.log all along?

Comment: there will be client logs in there, not zookeeper server logs

Comment: This answer is for Kafka 3.1.0. If the zookeeper bundled with this distribution is started with `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` (Refer:  https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart ), then the out-of-box `config/log4j.properties` sends the zookeeper logs to `<kafka_home_dir>/logs/server.log`. I was able to see WARN, INFO etc from zookeeper code in this log file. You could update the `config\log4j.properties` accordingly so that ERROR logs from zookeeper goes to a different file.

Comment: @BinitaBharati Feel free to write your own answer rather than a comment. The log4j files haven't changed in version 3.1.0